# ¿Como puedo insertar una venta utilizando Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo insertar una venta obteniendo una instancia de ambos modelos: ('departamentos', 'personas'), con relaciones de eloquent.

Answer (score 2):

Primero debes enviar desde el controlador los datos de `departamentos` y `personas`:

```
public function index(){
   $personas = Personas::all();
   $departamentos = Deparamentos::all();
   return view('ventas.index', [
       'personas' => $personas,
       'departamentos' => $departamentos
   ]);
}
```

Luego envías desde tu vista al controlador los `id's` de personas y departamentos y los recibes nuevamente al controlador pero al método `store`:

```
public fuction store(Request $request){
    $venta = new Venta($request->all()); // Asumiendo que desde la vista mandas los `names` de los `id's` así: departamentoId, personaId
    $venta->save();
    return back();
}
```